# Set ng-model name from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I set ng-model name from javascript?

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
    <input ng-model="?">
</div
```

JS

```
$scope.models= [
   {name: "modelOne"},
   {name: "modelTwo"},
   {name: "modelThree"}
];
```

Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: What do you want to set the model to...? `ng-model="model.name"` should work...

Comment: Do you want to set model name, so that later you could do `{{modelOne}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As simple as

```
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
  <input ng-model="model.name">
</div>
```

### Explanations

The `ng-repeat` loops through your `models` array and will add a `model` item in your scope on each iterations. From the HTML inside that `ng-repeat`, you can use `model` as if you had put it in your `$scope` from the controller.

Feel free to read more [documentation about ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

### If that is not what you want

If `$scope.models` is supposed to be a list of property names, for instance you want to actually edit `$scope.modelOne` rather than the string `modelOne` itself (on second read I think that could be what you mean), you cannot do that directly but you can use an object in between, i.e. edit `$scope.foo.modelOne` rather than `$scope.modelOne`

```
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
  <input ng-model="foo[model.name]">
</div>
```

And in your controller have

```
$scope.foo = {
  'modelOne':   'some text',
  'modelTwo':   'some other text',
  'modelThree': 'hello world'
}
```

Comment: Nice, but looks like not what OP wants.

Comment: @dfsq I also realized that on second thoughts, I have updated my answer by that time

Comment: Thank you and how can i change for example: value of second model?

Comment: @VáclavPavlíček depending on what you actually want (your question is a bit vague), one or the other solution will solve your problem. You don't need to worry about which model you will change: since it is in a `ng-repeat`, you will have as many inputs as you have models. To change the second model you will edit the second input.

Comment: *"you cannot do that directly but you can use an object in between"*. you can actually.

Comment: @dfsq I'm interested, how do you do that? Using ng-model, otherwise a hacky mix match of ng-init and ng-change (or custom directive) may do the trick.

Comment: No hacks, plain and straightforward. Maybe I will post the answer in case it can be useful for someone.

Comment: Oh yeah, using the `controller as` syntax I guess? Indeed that is an elegant answer, you can post it (or edit my answer if you like)

Comment: @floribon Check the answer, the idea is simply to use bracket notation. `this` points to the scope object, so you simply use `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in your question, it appears you want each `<input>` to have one of the models listed in your `models` array. If so, simply do:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
    <input ng-model="model.name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to set up `ngModel`'s by providing corresponding model names in variables, then you can still achieve it easily using old-good [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

So say you have variable `$scope.modelName = 'modelOne'` and you want to set up model so that you could use `{{modelOne}}` in template or `$scope.modelOne` in controller. It's very easy if you use bracket notation. In this case it will be `$scope[$scope.modelName] = 'something'`.

In you case, with `ngRepeat` there is a caveat because every iteration crates own child scope, so in order to set up model in proper scope, you need to use `$parent` reference to initial scope. So it will be:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
    <input ng-model="this.$parent[model.name]">
</div>
```

So the key here is that `this` in ngWhatever always point to the **scope object** (`$scope` in controller). And since it's an object you just use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access properties with variable name.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/DGj3H5qiyHKOxbbdtK8p?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the `this` tip, however that is still hacky since you need to use `$parent`. Here's a fork with the same spirit but using `controller as`: http://plnkr.co/edit/7R2d8mQXBxYvO4xilcfh?p=preview

Comment: It's not hacky, if there were no `ngRepeat` you wouldn't need `$parent`. But in this case it's absolutely needed and it's allright. And using `controller as` is cheating to me, because :)